# yo meanjs doesn't work :: yeoman doesn't see generator

Tags: node.js, yeoman, meanjs, yeoman-generator

When I run

```
yo meanjs
```

I get the following error.

```
Error meanjs 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name meanjs installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

However when I run...

```
npm search yeoman-generator
```

I get this...

```
generator-meanis                         A Meanis Generator for Yeoman                             
generator-meanjs                         MEAN.JS Official Yeoman Generator                         
generator-meanjs-table                   MEAN.JS Table Yeoman Generator
```

So I have meanjs generator installed, but it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual debugging step anytime you can't find a generator is to run:

```
yo doctor
```

This will look through your computer and make sure everything is configured correctly.

The only case it doesn't detect correctly is when sometime people have multiple version of npm installed and that messes up the node ecosystem.

**To recap**:

1. Run `yo doctor`
2. If *1.* doesn't work, then make sure you have a single npm installed on your machine.

If this doesn't work, then please open an issue on [yeoman/yo](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues) so we can add more checks to the `yo doctor` command.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the docs](https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs), you need to install both `yo` and the generator:

```
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-meanjs
```

Then you can do:

```
$ yo meanjs
```

Comment: I installed yo. When I type 'yo' into the command line i get the options 'Install a generator, Find some help, and Get me out of here!'

Comment: I have done that also. The problem comes when I run 'yo meanjs', as it says in my original question.

Comment: Ok... if you run `$ npm -g list | grep mean` do you see `generator-meanjs@0.1.12` in the list? And what version of Node do you have installed? (`$ node -v`)

Comment: I have v0.12.7 installed. And yes, when I run that i get generator-meanjs@0.1.12.

Comment: Weird... try restarting your shell/Terminal? And perhaps try reinstalling both just to be safe.

Comment: Also - when you installed `yo`, did it throw any kind of errors?

Comment: Restarting worked. I think I may delete this question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: woo! Glad to hear it. You may want to leave this here in case anyone has the same problem and can't figure it out.